# viewDidLoad & viewWillAppear conspiracy

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, viewdidload, viewwillappear

I have a favorites plist file when I try to load it like this

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"favorites" ofType:@"plist"];

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

self.allFavorites = array;
[array release];
```

}

nothing shows up in the tableView I've implemented

on the contrary when i cut & paste the same code in

```
-viewDidLoad:
```

method everything works fine....?

I need to put the code in viewWillAppear because user may add stuff to favorites to keep the favorites list updated.
& yes viewWillAppear do gets invoked, in the debug I've realized allFavorites array is empty in the viewWillAppear method...?

What can possibly be the problem....?

I've define allFavorites as follows

```
NSMutableArray *allFavorites;
```

then

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *allFavorites;
```

then

```
@synthesize allFavorites;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you update the backing store, call `reloadData` on the table view. It caches the data, so it doesn't have any clue that it's changed.